# Create excel file in R dynamically

Tags: r, dataframe, xlsx, data-cleaning

I have to copy the data from a data frame df1 and write it to  a new excel in a specific folder.The folder path is stored in a variable called fpath. There is a variable s which holds the filename. There are many files in the folder. I want the excel to be created dynamically for each file.

Now I am hard-coding the filename.

```
write.xlsx(df1,"C:/Users/Folder/results.xlsx")
```

Is there a way where the write.xlsx can dynamically name the excel that it is writing.
I tried the following way but it threw an error.

```
write.xlsx(df1,file=fpath + s)
```

Kindly suggest me if there is a way to dynamically name the created excel file without hard-coding the name in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `paste0`:

```
write.xlsx(df1, file = paste0(fpath, s))
```

Or depending if your path ends in `/` or not:

```
write.xlsx(df1, file = paste0(fpath, '/', s))
```

Comment: I tried both the methods. Unfortunately it is throwing an error "Error in createWorkbook(type = ext) : Unknown format 1".  Yes my file path ends in '/'

Comment: Your file name in `s` should end in `.xlsx`. Does it? You can either add that to `s` or do `write.xlsx(df1, file = paste0(fpath, s, '.xlsx'))`